# Annotation Track in Gviz

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, bioconductor

Does anyone with experience using the `bioconductor` package: `Gviz` know how to add an `AnnotationTrack` directly over a `DataTrack`?

For example, in `ggplot2` I can add to a prexitsting plot using + `geom_text`, but I haven't been able to locate a similar feature for `Gviz`

Thanks!

Comment: Have you read the vignette, e.g., `vignette("Gviz")` or at http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Gviz.html especially section 2 for a quick overview? I think you want to use `plotTracks()`, providing a list of tracks as the first argument.

Comment: Yes! I've been combing through the documentation... `plotTracks()` will plot both `AnnotationTrack` and `DataTrack` in the same plot/pdf - but one after the other, I was hoping to use Annotation Track feature to add a few key elements of a specific chromosomal region  directly over the data in `DataTrack` (for example, where the centromere falls in relation to a pattern observed in the data, etc.)

Comment: And I realize the centromere can be observed in the `IdeogramTrack` but again, I'm interested in the possibility of overlaying two tracks to make a particular relationship more visually apparent.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's not exactly what you want, one possible solution is to add a `HighlightTrack` that covers your region of interest. Although this won't specifically label / add the key elements on to your `DataTrack`, it will help highlight the alignment between differing `DataTracks`.

**Example:**

```
library(Gviz)
library(GenomicRanges)
data(geneModels)
data(cpgIslands)
gen <- genome(cpgIslands)
chr <- 1
start <- 120005434
end <- 129695434
itrack <- IdeogramTrack(genome = gen, chromosome = chr)
gtrack <- GenomeAxisTrack()
grtrack <- GeneRegionTrack(geneModels, genome = gen, chromosome = chr, name = "foo")
htrack <- HighlightTrack(trackList = list(gtrack, grtrack), start = 121535434, end = 124535434, chromosome = chr)
plotTracks(list(itrack, htrack), from = start, to = end)
```

**Graphical output**

[image]

Although the `grtrack` is empty, it demonstrates how the `HighlightTrack` will span the specified `DataTracks` (in this case, `grtrack` and `gtrack`).

See the [GViz documentation](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Gviz.html) for more on info.